# Family visit visa to UK for Moroccan citizen

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, moroccan-citizens

I'm a Moroccan citizen. I want to visit my husband in the UK. He and our daughter are British citizens. What do I need to do to get a visa?

Comment: To be clear, do you want to visit him in the UK and then leave or do you want to stay with him in the UK?

Comment: I suspect you'd be more likely to be accepted on a spousal settlement visa than a general visit visa. Unless you have very strong ties to Morocco, it would be reasonable to assume you want to live with your family in the UK permanently and so the visa office would think that you plan to overstay a visit visa. Guidance is here https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/partner-spouse